# difference between turning point & tipping point?

Tags: vocabulary

Could anyone possibly elaborate the difference between these? and whether they could use interchangeably?

Furthermore, which one is used in mathematics, so on?

I am wondering **how** the term tipping point could be used for marriage of gays.

**turning point**

tipping point

Any help would be appreciated

[enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1KjqKxwvMA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tipping point is where some force, continuing to act upon something, pushes it to the point where gravity is greater than some counterbalancing force, and the thing (e.g. a glass of wine, a domino, a rickety shed ) falls or "tips" over.

A turning point is when any entity that can act (person, organization, country, etc)  is confronted with circumstances that demand a change of plan or a different approach.

They have different connotations.

Answer (score 0):

Turning point in Math:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point

Tipping points in Math:
https://www.dur.ac.uk/ihrr/tippingpoints/mathematicaltippingpoints/